# How to 'leave pair out' where each test pair consists of [0 1]

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am building a machine learning classifier and want to use 'leave pair out' cross-validation, with non-overlapping pairs, where each pair contains one instance from the negative class and one from the positive, i.e. the ground truth labels or `y` values in each test set fold would be  `[0 1]`.

I can't work out how to achieve this in Scikit learn. I have 50 instances (with 25 in each class) so I can do:

`split = KFold(n_splits=50 // 2, shuffle=True, random_state=42)`

to get non-overlapping pairs but this doesn't give me test sets of `[0 1]`. I have looked at the documentation for `LeavePGroupsOut` but this doesn't seem to be what I want.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you may want [StratifiedKFold](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold.html). This class creates folds while maintaining the label balance; combined with your current technique of using 25 folds, that should do the trick.

Comment: Ahh of course! Thank you! That has indeed done the trick.